# Logic behind checking if a number is a Palindrome

Tags: java, loops, palindrome

I have made a program to check if a number is palindrome but unable to understand --When n=1 and I do n/10 should it not be = 0 as int n = 1/10 = 0.1=0 so loop should stop ? But it prints as 1 and then 0 . How does that happen ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Pallinnumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int y =reversenum(1234);
        System.out.println(y);
        Pallinnumber.Pallinnum(12);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int x = s.nextInt();
        int z= reversenum(x);
       System.out.println(z);

}

    public static int reversenum(int n)
    {
        int num=0;
        while(n>0)
        {
            num = num*10;
            num=num+n%10;
            n=n/10;
            System.out.println(n);      

        }
    return num;
    }
public static boolean Pallinnum(int n)
{
    if(n==reversenum(n)){
        System.out.println("It is a Pallindrome number");
        return true;
    }
    else 
        {   

            System.out.println("It is not an Pallindrome number");
            return false ;

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Step 1: Format you code correctly.

Comment: this is the kind of program that should be solved first using a pen and paper, IMO. Then the code will be clear for you.

Comment: Step 2: the task of checking whether a number is a decimal palindrome is most easily seen as a two-step process: first, convert the number to a string. Then check if the string is symmetrical.

Comment: And note that it is sufficient to check only one half of the number string and compare it with the reversed other half, otherwise you do checks twice.

Comment: mvw- i was just trying an alternative method.. leo- My bad ...I got it now after using pen and paper !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code: when `n` is `1`, you do `n /= 10` *after* adding `n%10` to the running total (i.e. `num`). This makes `num` equal `1`, which is what you want.

By the time your loop prints zero, `num` is already equal to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's int arithmetic, so: 1/10 = 0

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the solution is perfect.

Have u tried  System.out.println(1/10); Interestingly, it also displays 0. Its all about math & compiler.

```
package univ;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Pallinnumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int x = s.nextInt();
        int z= reversenum(x);
       System.out.println(z);
       Pallinnum(z);

}

    public static int reversenum(int n)
    {
        int num=0;
        while(n>0)
        {
            num = num*10;
            num=num+n%10;
            n/=10;
        }
    return num;
    }
public static boolean Pallinnum(int n)
{
    if(n==reversenum(n)){
        System.out.println("It is a Pallindrome number");
        return true;
    }
    else 
        {   

            System.out.println("It is not an Pallindrome number");
            return false ;

        }
    }
}
```